# Issues in data regarding a program for data mining Google stock (GOOGLE) information from 2004-2008

Tags: python, data-mining

Ok this program is my Final for computer science and i have worked on it a lot and i have hit a brick wall so i am swallowing my pride and pleading the kind people of Stack overflow for aid.  The purpose of this program (written in python 3.3) is to take a file of stock information and then over four years and then print the best six months and the worse six months. I can get it to print months and years but it is all from September of 2004. could someone please help show me where i went wrong?

Thanks in advance 
here is the code

```
import operator
def get_data_list(file_name):
    data_file = open(file_name, "r") 
    data_list = []    # always start with an open list
    for line_str in data_file:
        data_list.append(line_str.strip().split(','))  # removes all commas from the csv file
    return data_list
def get_monthly_averages_list(data_list):     # This function does the math to determine the average
    monthly_average_list = []
    monthly_average = 0.0
    monthly_volume = 0.0
    extremly_important_variable = '09'
    yearly =  '2008'
    for line in data_list:
        month = line[0].split('/')[0]
        year = line[0].split('/')[2]
        close = float( line [6])
        volume = float( line [5])
        monthly_average += close*volume
        monthly_volume += volume
        if month != extremly_important_variable:
            new_monthly_average = round(monthly_average/monthly_volume,2)
            average_tuple = (extremly_important_variable, yearly, new_monthly_average)
            monthly_average_list.append(average_tuple)
        extremely_important_variable = month
        yearly = year

    return monthly_average_list
def monthly_average_info(monthly_average_list):
    K = 0
    print('worst monthly averages for Google were:')
    for K in range (1,7):

       monthly_average_list[::-1]
       monthly_average_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
       test = (monthly_average_list[K][0] + ' ' + monthly_average_list[K][1] + ' ' + str(monthly_average_list[K][2]))   
       print(test)
    print ( "6 best months for google were:")
    for x in range (1,7):
       monthly_average_list[::-1].sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2))
       Test2 = (monthly_average_list[x][0] + ' ' + monthly_average_list[x][1] + ' '  + str(monthly_average_list[x][2]))
       print(Test2)

Datalist = get_data_list('table.csv')
Datalist.pop(0)
monthly_average_list = get_monthly_averages_list(Datalist)
monthly_average_info(monthly_average_list)
```

Comment: Google's ticker was GOOG, not GOOGL, in the timeframe you discuss (though what was traded then corresponds to what is now GOOGL).